# Getting rid of "You have gone fullscreen" message in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

I find that the "you have gone fullscreen" popup in Chrome (see it for yourself by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>) is extremely annoying, and I really want to get rid of it. After Googling for a while, I've come up short.

Is there any way, perhaps through an extension or registry setting, to remove this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ALWAYS use Chrome in fullscreen, add the argument `--kiosk` on your shortcut.

As a matter of fact, there is no solution around the internet for this, as I have searched for it with no avail for some time now.

Recently I discovered it is a chrome feature and as such not removable at the moment; perhaps a future update will allow to disable it.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked like a charm! Thank you! :)